# Is this animated GIF showing Illustrator step by step drawings easy to understand?

Tags: vector, drawing, gif, critique, education

I'm trying to make some short animated gifs about Illustrator, with little step-by-step drawings exercises.

I could put some explanatory text in some frames but I would prefer not to do that. Maybe later, it depends on where it ends up, I can add a text line with the used tools.

That's why I would like to know if something like the animation below is understandable enough for someone having a basic AI knowledge.

[image: chair]

*Thanks for all the comments. Sometimes when you're immersed in a project, however small, you get a little blind. That's why I put the question. Each comment is very useful and I will keep everything in mind.*

Comment: Want to link us to your website when it's done?

Comment: @LateralTerminal i will, but all of you put me a lot of homework to do :-) I'm not sure how long it will take.

Comment: Do you aim at teaching a live audience or online synchronous/asynchronous?

Comment: The objective is not to teach, simply to catch for a minute an audience:
• For those who have an idea about vector drawing, they will try to interpret how it is done.
• For those who do not know vector drawing, it will only be an animation, even if i put the step by step with shortcuts and tools.

That's why I accepted @Webster 's answer, because clarified me the doubt I had, not just for the animation, but for the objective: — it's just an animated graphic about an illustration process —

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see, follow or understand(?) the steps in creating the chair.

Nothing is conveyed about how to do it, which tools are used with which shortcuts, except the changing cursor and highlighted nodes.

If this will be a teaching tutorial it'll need more explanation.

If it's a graphic about the illustration process then it works well as is.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, it is not a tutorial and of course not a teaching resource, it's just a drawing made with AI tools. I'm trying to make it as comprehensible as possible, but simple, clear, without too much noise. After reading all the comments, I will crop it and add some keys and shortcuts on the animation, but as secondary thing.

Answer (score 19):

I think without knowing what tools did what, what shortcuts did what, and how to do simple things such as reverse the fill/stroke, the gif may be lacking in detail for inexperienced users. There's merely *too much* "unknown" if you aren't familiar with the functionality of tools/shortcuts  in Illustrator.

[image]

Conversely, to me, it's very easy, clear, and simple if you *do* understand the tools, functions, and shortcuts. So perhaps with so little explanation that particular gif could be an "intermediate user" gif?

Comment: Yes, i know about the explanation... It has to be in English and Spanish, that's why i'm trying to avoid that. I would like to make it universal, finding a way to explain it with no text. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Minor additional thing -- also show where you're clicking. Many screen recorders will record little "bubbles" expanding from where you click, and I'm sure you can find software to make that happen on-screen for a screen recorder to pick up. (Also, the modifiers generally have language-agnostic symbols -- a Mac's Command symbol is the same on any keyboard layout, AFAIK, even if the location changes)

Comment: note: moving the entire string when adding a character at the end of it to keep it always centered makes it very hard to read because the text is always moving away from where you're trying to look at

Comment: @user1306322 the above gif is merely a *sample* it's unlikely you would randomly press modifiers one after the other as in the sample gif. In most instances all the modifiers would be depressed at one time.

Comment: Which tool adds in the keyboard clicks?

Comment: @WELZ there are a number of them. It kind of depends upon the OS you are using. On a Mac - iShowU, ScreenFlow, Iris, I think Camtasia

Answer (score 10):

There's a few things you could do to improve this good idea and not make it horrible.

1. You definitely need to add screen keys.
2. You should break it up into steps and use multiple gifs to show what you've done instead of just one long gif.
   This eliminates the issue Scott raised that gifs are too long.
3. Supplement the gif with a description of what you've done.
4. Provide a download file with the complete project.

---

EDIT: I thought about this some more.

## Gif technology is awful if you're not hosting funny short clips.

Gif is by far the worst video compression ever invented.
Google and imgur basically tried to irradiate gif completely with webm but failed massively.

What Google does now when you search for animated gifs is the preview is re-encoded as VP9, h264 or something similar. It saves A LOT of space and loads a lot faster. When you click on the preview it loads the actual gif file.

Using a real video compression format will have a lot of disadvantages.
For one the license involved for using [h264 is expensive](https://www.engadget.com/2010/05/04/know-your-rights-h-264-patent-licensing-and-you/). You'd have to rely on another service like YouTube to host it so you don't have to worry about being sued. Your site visitors can't download the videos from YouTube easily like they could with a gif.

If you don't want to rely on YouTube as a host you could encode it in an open source video format.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_codecs

Honestly I'm not even sure about the legality of some of the open source codecs. That's why google has been working on AV1 which still sucks.

---

## Just use YouTube

Whatever short clips you'd save as gif you should just host on YouTube and embed it on your website. You don't have to make a long YouTube tutorial like everyone else does. Just break it in pieces like you would with gif and embed the videos in the same places next to supplemental text explanations like I said you should do with the gifs. Everything will load a lot faster on your site.

---

EDIT 2:

To clarify some noise in the comments.

There's no real difference between a YouTube video and a Gif.
They are both video formats.
The difference being that a YouTube video would load faster, have better color, and would also have the ability to pause (it's very important to pause).

.Gif is going to give you a lot of artifacts and improperly display colors because that's how gif works.

So wherever on your website you would place that 4 second gif instead it would be a 4 second video.
Why would you still want to use gif at this point?
If you use video from YouTube you can hide the videos from the public so that it's only seen on your website.

In the end if you do it the way I'm suggesting it will save you a lot of stress provide higher quality at a smaller size and it will allow people to easily view it on mobile phones that don't have high speed data.

Comment: Good, i will take a look.

Comment: Honestly we should be using embedded videos here instead of gifs but stackexchange doesn't support embedded videos into answers so that's why we use gifs. The only reason we use gifs here.

Comment: Realize that due to Terms of Service, utilizing services such as YouTube *can*  relinquish *rights* to original content. That's not always a desired option. Heck... even here, once you post an image, it's free to everyone under a [Creative Commons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309025/is-my-copyrighted-artwork-protected-if-i-upload-it-to-a-post) License. The only way to prevent such licensing is to host the content yourself where you have ultimate control. There are also services such as https://giphy.com/ which uses video and *may* offer a better alternative to YouTube.

Comment: @Scott That's not true. If you upload something to YouTube you get to choose a checkbox for that. You can retain copyright if you chose the right options. YouTube can always delete your video if someone else claims copyright but that's another matter.

Comment: Actually YouTube assigns a very similar CC-By license to uploaded content : https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797468?hl=en&ref_topic=2778546 You are mistaken if you think others can't use your YouTube content. As long as they adhere to the CC license, then can. It's the same as posting images here. You aren't "giving up" your copyright, you are *allowing* free use of anything you upload.

Comment: @Scott Right I know about that but that license is an option. I've uploaded content to YouTube before without CC. I'm going to double check though.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm wrong. I very well could be. I merely think if you have the ability to host your own content, do so.. then create marketing materials that you an upload elsewhere. So if they are shared inadvertently, they all send users back to you. In other words.. don't *rent* space if you have the ability to *own* your space. `:)`

Comment: @LateralTerminal Anyway, about the Youtube staff, there are already very good sites with AI Youtube tutorials like https://www.jasonsecrest.com/ . I still interested in short gifs, maybe in pieces as all of you said, but simple, easy to understand and short.

Comment: @Scott You're wrong I just checked. You can upload and choose standard YouTube license instead of CC license.  I uploaded a video to check. I started to second guess myself.

Comment: @Danielillo I'm saying that gif is just a bad video format. Instead of using short .gif you would use .mp4. The YouTube videos can be hidden on the channel so nobody can search for them. That way it's totally different than just a YouTube channel that has tutorials. The point I'm making is everything would be the same just the format would be different instead of gif.

Comment: You still grant YouTube the rights to use the video with the "standard" license. `:)` So basically.. you tell Google they can use it. In the age of data farming, that's quite an asset to relinquish. `:)`

Comment: @Scott Technically you're only giving them the right to delete your video when they feel like it or if there's cause (if you're a sex predator or something.) But you are not in any way relinquishing your copyright. You own that video. YouTube does not in anyway own your video. They can not monetize or sell it.

Comment: @Scott It does suck that you're giving away some rights. But if you put anything out in the public that's what happens. It wouldn't matter if you give it to google or vimeo or fox news.  The point is you don't have to worry about being sued by h264 patent holders :)

Comment: Uhm.. they **are** monetizing it the moment you upload it. How do you think YouTube acquires traffic to sell ads? User-provided content they get for free. My point is. *you* can monetize it yourself without giving away free content to other hosting services. Sorry I got this so off track `:)` it really wasn't my intention. And uhm there's a **huge** difference between a YouTube video and a gif. That last edit is really incorrect in my opinion.

Comment: Actually there are no ads unless you monetize the video yourself. @Scott If you see ads they are making money and YouTube is making money. YouTube only makes money off ads you allow them to monetize. That's why there are still a lot of videos with no ads still on YouTube. I don't mind you going off track I like talking about YouTube. It's something I've studied for a while.

Comment: There does exist a (sometimes important) difference between a GIF and a YouTube video: you can't always embed a YT video where you'd like to. E.g. on StackExchange sites, where GIF works flawlessly. IIRC, some of the SE sites do support them (Movies.SE, SciFi.SE), but not all.

Comment: @Ruslan I said that already. That's obvious. It has nothing to do with stack exchange he's making a website. It's a different file type but its still just a compressed video so it's the same thing in this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

I sporadically use Illustrator but do have full Photoshop knowledge.

I could vaguely guess which tools you are using but have no idea what shortcodes you are pressing... I wouldn't know how to  select part of that path and then magically flip it over like you did.

So my guess is someone with more extensive knowledge than 'sporadically' would understand it, but then I'm wondering if they wouldn't already know how to create a drawing like this?

Something else I am personally worried about is the lack of a pause button, if I ever lose track it will be hard to get back in I think.

Comment: You are right about the shortcuts. The problem is not just the shortcut, but it must be followed with the explanation about what it does: Press "E" to make a free scale :-(, to long.  I still thinking how to manage this.

Comment: @Danielillo just a quick mind spin, maybe you can fix the button/combination in one of the corners? So list 'command + c' if you need to copy or something like that. I've seen games do this often.

Comment: yes, remember must be for Mac and Win: +A / Ctrl+A

Answer (score 4):

I'd leave the gif, unless it is a really short animation, and use a video instead. The ability to pause and scroll makes it much easier to watch-and-try-it-yourself.

I'd add small panel in one corner that will diplay the keys pressed (V for select, etc.) and what it means (Select tool), the keys that are pressed and held (Alt for drag the copy) and indicators what mouse buttons are clicked, double clicked or held.

And in the first lesson, describe what those letters and incons of yours mean. You can sacrifice a couple of first frames to show titles just to remind what the panel means.

Comment: I know what you mean. In fact the gif of the question is a video, converted to gif and re-edited. For the moment I like the gif retro touch, i just need to think about the design with some universal explanation. Universal means no language and Mac-Win.

Comment: @Danielillo, I can just imagine a bunch of people watching through the whole thing over and over because they missed something. It doesn't have to have sound to justify using a video format... If you keep it a video, you'll have more freedom in how you present it. Like with bells and whistles such as play and pause and timeline scrubbing. Besides if it's a gif, you'll have huge pressure in keeping everything short or else it's just too long to make any sense being a gif. Like 2 minutes in and you miss one step "well, I guess I load the page again or something..."

Comment: @Joonas That's why i have to make it shorter. Anyway, this sentence "...a bunch of people watching through the whole thing over and over ..." I think it's a bit exaggerated ;-), it is not the last Gaga video! Anyway, as i wrote on the question comments, i feel pressed now to make a whole project. I will let you know all when it's done to get your critics.

Comment: @Danielillo, I'd like to see a beginner or even seasoned AI user keeping up with that, if the point is to follow what is being made in the gif. As I understood they are tutorials of some sort?

Comment: @Joonas I guess i will cut out each piece and put links to the step by step. But is something that I just have in mind. This chair is an old draw I had on my teaching's facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.124268424255836.24752.111716732177672&type=3

Comment: @Danielillo There is a big difference between pressing V because the animation says so and pressing V because it is a shortcut to select tool. I can see no way, how to do such totorial without any word. On the other hand, if you use just tool names, it is easier to translate it. If you are in rush, place the test descriptions in subtitles.

Comment: @Crowley Yes, I am convinced of that after all the comments. But everybody thinks in just one OS, must be Mac shorcut + Win shorcut + the key + the tool + the explanation.  I have an idea but I have to make it.

Comment: @Danielillo windows have ctrl, alt and shift. Apple has different buttons to alter the shortcuts. If it is possible, you can use pear symbol for Ctrl, peach for Alt and cherry for Shift. (I'm sorry I've never used a Mac). Or display Apple shortcut above and windows shortcut below.

Comment: @Danielillo if you dont expect people to watch this many times what is it for? Remember if somebody wants to do the example they need to context switch from your gif to AI and by that they lost the context. Now they need to wait untill its tgere again, do it wait again. This is why its better if its split to several gifs.

Comment: Note that you can link to specific points in the video, and play a section in a loop. I'd keep the video as an overview of the whole process, and add a list of the steps in HTML, showing the relevant tools and keys, with each step linked to the relevant section in the video.

Answer (score 3):

I have rather suprisingly like scott no problem in following what you do, but then if you showed me the last picture i would know how to do it anyway.

But in my experience at teaching id say the following: The gif is both too fast and too long. See you can not rewind or stop the gif so it should be slower, but it is also too long to follow if you try to do the example so i would split the gif up into separate gifs if possible and put a textual explanation between the separate steps.

Remember that doing is different context from seeing. So the user needs to switch to doing, by that they lost a lot that they saw. This forces the user to rewind, in this case waie, do, wait, do. But id say its fine as a overview just as long as its clearly communicated and tgeres better instructions to follow.

Comment: I guess i will make different levels gifs: beginner, medium level and "half" advanced.

Comment: @Danielillo if all you have is a hammer then either your option is to treat everything as a nail or go to the hardware store.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question bluntly: no it is not easy to understand.

From your questions + comments spread out over the answers it seems you have the following requirements:

- Short animations
- No language
- No OS specific instructions

Other users already provided excellent suggestions, however I feel that the latter two requirements are not fully met by them. 
[@Crowley](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/79742/crowley) provided [an answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109522/8845) which I think is very helpful, especially this part:

> I'd add small panel in one corner that will diplay the keys pressed (V for select, etc.) and what it means (Select tool), the keys that are pressed and held (Alt for drag the copy) and indicators what mouse buttons are clicked, double clicked or held.

But why *add* a panel in a corner while Illustrator already has this panel built in with language independent icons? The Tools panel can be shown alongside the image, allowing the student to see what tools are clicked:

[image]

This covers your `No language` requirement. To slim it down, you could use a custom Tools panel that only shows the relevant tools for the shown instruction:

[image]

However, I don't think you can avoid using OS specific keyboard shortcuts altogether. Otherwise you do not have any means of indicating that one has to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> when rotating to snap to 45<sup>o</sup> or  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> when using the Free Transform Tool.

Comment: My original idea is to make simple animated illustrations with Illustrator. Many comments point to an Illustrator tutorial, and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. My interest is finding a middle point between an animation and an exercise, avoiding the tutorial. If i put the AI interface on it, breaks totally the essence of the work i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Danielillo Ok, but that was not clear from your question. I think it would be good for the answer quality (and for your satisfaction) if you sit down for a minute and think what you want to ask and which boundary conditions you have (i.e.: not a tutorial, no language, simple, etc...). Then edit the question accordingly. Now your requirements are spread over multiple comments, making it very hard to come up with a satisfactory answer. I am happy to think about your question if it's clearly defined and there's no "moving target".

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it. At the moment I am very grateful for what they have given me: a good number of honest criticisms and several comments (including yours) with which I am very satisfied and from which I will take good advantage to improve my project. In fact, thanks to these comments I have reached the conclusions you mention and I did not take into account before.